# pass object to c# class to ascx

Tags: asp.net, webforms, sharepoint-2013

I have created Visual Web Part in visual studio 2013 using C#. Now in this I have main C# class along with ascx with usercontrol. I got two question.

1. how can I pass object/ variable or array from c# class to ascx web??

### c# class

```
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public partial class VisualWebPart1 : WebPart
{  
    public VisualWebPart1()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        InitializeControl();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        SPSite _site = SPContext.Current.Web.Site; 
        SPWeb _web = _site.OpenWeb();

        int[] myvar = new int[5] { 99, 98, 92, 97, 95 };

        foreach(var item in myvar)
        {
            var b1 = item;

            //how I send myvar value to ascx page??????????????                
        }
    }
}
```

### ascx page

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

<br /><br />

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

2. my second question is how to print loop in gridview or in textbox (textbox1)?? with new lines with each iteration of loop

Comment: pass it through session variable and iterate through code behind of .ascx

Comment: create a public property on the user control and pass the variable to that

Answer (score 1):

That will solve your problem. In addition it may not be the best solution.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
      if (!this.IsInEditMode)//in display Mode
      {

            int[] myvar = new int[5] { 99, 98, 92, 97, 95 };
            string returnHtml = "";
            foreach(var item in myvar)
            {
               returnHtml += item.ToString() +"<br />";             
            }
            Label1.innerText = returnHtml;
      }
}
```

You should understand if the page mode in Edit Or display. Use below.

```
 private bool IsInEditMode
    {
        get
        {
            SPWebPartManager currentWebPartManager = (SPWebPartManager)WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(this.Page);
            return (((currentWebPartManager != null) && !base.IsStandalone) && currentWebPartManager.GetDisplayMode().AllowPageDesign);
        }
    }
```